# Error by authenticating user! when i am trying to open login page in twitter

Tags: blackberry, twitter

I downloaded the  TwitterAPIME-RIM-OAuthSample.zip file from [Project Kenai](http://kenai.com/projects/twitterapime/downloads/directory/Miscellaneous).
And I registered my application on [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com) successfully.

I received a consumer key and consumer secret. And I'm using the following code to login:

```java
public BrowserFieldScreen() {
   setTitle("Twitter API ME - OAuth");
   BrowserContentManager browserMngr = new BrowserContentManager(0);
   RenderingOptions rendOptions = browserMngr.getRenderingSession().getRenderingOptions();
   rendOptions.setProperty(RenderingOptions.CORE_OPTIONS_GUID,
      RenderingOptions.SHOW_IMAGES_IN_HTML,
      false);
   add(browserMngr);
   BrowserContentManagerOAuthDialogWrapper pageWrapper =new BrowserContentManagerOAuthDialogWrapper(browserMngr);

   pageWrapper.setConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
   pageWrapper.setConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
   pageWrapper.setCallbackUrl(CALLBACK_URL);
   pageWrapper.setOAuthListener(this);

   try {
      pageWrapper.login();
   } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      System.out.println("error: "+e.getMessage());
   }
}
```

After a while I found the following message in my console: `Error by authenticating user!`

So what am I doing wrong here? Do I need to change any permissions?

*Note: If I use my old keys which I registered 6 months ago it's working fine.*

Comment: The language of the login page is not in English. So how you login to twitter ?

Answer (score 0):

please Enter CallbackURl in your Twitter Application so go to Twitter App Setting and Add callbackurl if no you can use http://www.someurl.com

because In Desktop Application must define CallbackUrl ..

i solve this problem by update in application setting .not any need to change the Code..

Comment: The language is not english. so how to login to the twitter ?

Comment: you just run the above code, then it will show the Login page of Twitter. The twitter page is not in English Language.Its in Some other language.

Comment: Its Fetch the Localization and send twitter according to your local language but your device is not suppoerted that language so that This type of View is Appear.

Comment: try to conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en");
      conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US"); in your Request sending

Comment: Gajja - How to add conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en"); conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");  ?.its not possible. iam using BrowserContentManagerOAuthDialogWrapper. how to do that ?.

Answer (score 0):

you just run the above code, then it will show the Login page of Twitter. The twitter page is not in English Language.Its in Some other language.
[image]